# Backspace character (^H, U+0008) is displayed in preview, disappears when rendered on the actual page

Tags: discussion, bug, editor

Question: [How to use '\b' with fmt.Println()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71892768/how-to-use-b-with-fmt-println)

The expected output as shown in the edit section:

[image: expected output]

Actual output:

**Note the missing boxes (representing an unknown character?)**

[image: Actual output]

Comment: On my side, I don't even see the box: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jnll1.png

Comment: @Sabito錆兎standswithUkraine, I originally thought this was a browser issue, but I don't think so anymore for had this been one, the box wouldn't show up even in "This is how the post will look like" section of the edit mode.

Comment: @justanotherguy Do you still see it here? https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71892768/edit

Comment: Don't even get me started. The number of times I've written a well-formatted post and had to go back and fix line breaks inside of inline formatted code when the preview showed it fine is enormous.

Comment: @AnnZen, no I don't

Comment: Afaik, there's some server side validations and cleaning.

Comment: This is a bug, but have you tried a code block? Those are sometimes formatted a bit differently than inline code. Also, while you should post text as text as a general rule, if you have a scenario where you're unable to get the text to display what you're asking about, that would be one time where posting text as an image (in your original question) may actually be appropriate. Another option may be to replace the character with whatever character you're actually seeing, e.g. the square unicode character (□), but do be sure to note that you're doing this in the question.

Comment: Does it look like ‘�’ by any chance?

Comment: Because what it actually *is* is the actual backspace character you expected to be output, going by <https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/0f535b5a-6201-48fb-889e-9ab3077fba5b/view-source>.

Comment: Similar Meta SE post (which I happen to have authored): [Certain escape characters can be copied while editing, but not after](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377341/1156839)

Comment: @NotThatGuy, yes. I have tried code-block too

Comment: How should arbitrary binary data be handled? Use hex dumps? [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encode it? Are [Unicode control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_control_characters), e.g. [BS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#BS), special? There must be plenty of meta posts about this.

Comment: I suggest literally dumping it as it. That happens to be usually the most helpful (and also the most annoying) way.

Answer (score 2):

This is how the character renders in my Firefox ESR 91 on Debian:

[image: Screenshot of Stack Overflow’s post editor and preview; in the editor, the backspace character is displayed as a [0 0 0 8] code point box. In the preview below it, the character is invisible.]

The backspace character clearly visible in the edit box, but not in the preview.  However, if I select the text in the preview, copy and paste it, the backspace character is present.  It just isn’t visible on the page.

Given how inconsistently it renders in various circumstances, perhaps it is better to avoid inputting it directly anyway.  In this case, I think it is best to replace it by ‘�’, with a note below; this is what I ended up doing to the original question.  In other circumstances, ‘␈’ might be a better replacement.

Answer (score 2):

Character escape `\b` technically outputs Unicode character U+0008, so it doesn't delete previous character, but it adds a new character to the string.

Some environments (e.g., a [VT100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100) compatible Unix terminal) will *interpret* U+0008 by moving the text caret one step towards left and overwrite the following content at that position (note that if nothing follows, there's nothing to overwrite, so this is not the same as delete).

If you execute the code in some other context that interprets the U+0008 as a visible character, you'll end up with some kind of representation of character U+0008 in the position you added the character escape `\b`. Common options are some kind of broken graphics, "�" (U+FFFD replacement character), "␈" (U+2408 symbol for backspace) or an empty string.

In my experience, U+0008 getting interpreted as "delete previous character" in practice is pretty rare outside a terminal context.

Comment: This would fit as an answer under [the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71892768/), not this one.